# SQL [Oracle] comparing multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem... I have table with informations about employees and I have to select sections, where is more employees without title then with ING title. How can i do that ? Why cant I use this mine SQL code ? It says single-row subquery returns more than one row. But i need to compare more than 1 row.

Thank for help :)

```
select section_number from employe where
 (select count(section_number) from employe where title='ING' group by section_number) 
> 
(select count(section_number) from employe where title IS NULL group by section_number) 
group by section_number;
```

Comment: is your group by column correct ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below select

```
With ing_title as (select count(1) sec_ing,
section_number from employe where title='ING' 
group by section_number),

null_title as ( select count(1) sec_null,
section_number from employe where title is null group by section_number)

select ing_title.section_number 
from ing_title,null_title
where ing_title.sec_ing > null_title.sec_null
and ing_title.section_number=null_title.section_number
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didnt even know that i can define 2 new tables from my table and then select that... :)

Answer (score 0):

according to descriptions in the question, I think you need this:

```
select count(section_number),title 
from employe 
where title is null or title='ING' 
group by title 
Order by title nulls first
```

it will give you number of employees with no title and number of employees with title='ING'